# Error while deploying the tables using powershell script into Azure table storage

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am running the below script and passing the script parameters for the $fileObj through powershell script using arguments section in VSTS powershell task.I am trying to deploy table data into Azure table storage. I have table data in .csv files and I am trying to deploy those table entities using powershell script and deploying into azure table storage.The below script is not deploying the table entities and failing with error. Could any one please help me out.
I have attached the error log in onedrive location:  https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AEh2aAOnbmuzq9U&cid=5599285D52BD31F3&id=5599285D52BD31F3%21900&parId=root&action=locate

```
foreach($fo in $fileObj){
 Write-Host $fo.filepath
 $csv = Import-CSV $fo.filepath
  $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")
  foreach($line in $csv)
    {
    Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)"
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
        foreach($c in $cArray){
     Write-Host "$c,$($line.$c)"
 $entity.Properties.Add($c,$line.$c)
 }
 $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
 }
}

$subscriptionName = ""
$resourceGroupName = ""
$storageAccountName = ""
$location = ""

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = ""

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
```

Comment: Can anyone please respond to my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your mentioned log, I find that it seems that your csv column name is not corresponding to your code. And your CSV file format with 2 Colunms named Partitionkey and Rowkey is not correct. Please have a try to use the following demo code and csv file format. It works correctly on myside.

```
$resourceGroup ="resourceGroup name"
$storageAccount = "storage account Name"
$tableName = "table name"
$storageAccountKey = "storage key"
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -
StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey 

######### Add removing table and create table code #######
try
{
    Write-Host "Start to remove table $tableName, please wait a moment..."

    Remove-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -Force # Remove the Azure table

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 # waiting for removing table, you could change it according to your table 

    Write-Host "$tableName table has been removed"
}
catch
{
   Write-Host "$tableName is not existing"
}
Write-Host "Start to create $tableName table"

New-AzureStorageTable -Name  $tableName -Context $ctx  # Create new azure storage table

##########Add removing table and create table code ############

$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx 
$csvPath ='csv file path'
$cols = "Label_Usage,Label_Value,Usage_Location" #should be corrensponding to your csv column exclude Partitionkey and RowKey
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath
$number = 0
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation]$batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation
foreach($line in $csv)
{ 
     $number++
     $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
     $colArray = $cols.split(",")
     Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)" #output partitionkey and rowKey value
     foreach($colName in $colArray)
     {
         Write-Host "$colName,$($line.$colName)" #output column name and value
        $entity.Properties.Add($colName,$line.$colName)
     }
    if($number -le 100)
    {
        $batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($entity) # Changed code
    }
    else
    {   $number =0
        $result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
   [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation]$batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation
    }
}
if($batchOperation.Count -ne 0)
{
 $result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
}
```

**Note:** For batch operation requires records in the CSV file with **the same partition key** value.

---

**csv file example format**

[image]

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: ,Thanks for responding to this issue as I have been waiting for people to help me out on this.I have shared the error log file @ https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhw-m9I5DmLRSpYFA   .Please check the error and help me out.I am still facing the error.

Comment: According to your it seems that it is upto [azure table batch operation limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablebatchoperation?view=azure-dotnet). `A batch operation may contain up to 100 individual table operations, with the requirement that each operation entity must have same partition key. A batch with a retrieve operation cannot contain any other operations. Note that the total payload of a batch operation is limited to 4MB.`

Comment: I have updated the demo code, I also test it on my side, it works correctly.

Comment: I have used your script,its deployed all the contents.But My issue is different like,when I add any new entry and delete existing entry or modified the existing entry it should update in the azure tables but its not updating.Please find my latest log and sampletable.csv file updated with inserting one row,deleted one row,modified one row attached in one drive @  https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhxOC8nB7IZfac3vY .  Please try to insert and delete and modify entities and try to deploy.Then you will come to know about my issue.

Comment: If it is resolved, please have mark it  as an answer to closed it. And  raise a new thread about you mentioned issue that could let more communities easily to search and  give help to you.

Comment: it's not resolved yet. As per my requirement,I want to insert, delete, replace the entities in the table using one script. The script which you have given is only inserting.

Comment: Please help me out on deleting and replacing and updating the entire table when any change happened in the csv files

Comment: You could get more detail info about operation Azure storage table method from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablebatchoperation?view=azure-dotnet), in your case you could to use `$batchOperation.InsertOrReplace(ITableEntity)` and `$batchOperation.Remove(ITableEntity)`. You could debug the script code locally. By the way, **SO**  it is not a place to ask whole solution, it is a technical resolved place.

Comment: thanks for your answer. how can I add those 2 functions in my current script? I am not sure how to do locally. I am new to azure and vsts. Please advise me. Please help me on updating with the delete and insert replace operations in the scripts kindly.

Comment: You could install the [Azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-5.0.0) in the Windows machine. And debug the code with [Powershell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-5.1). You also could use the [Azure storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) during test. And use the [Azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to view the table content.

Comment: You could look into the mentioned link and try to code and debug it locally, If I have free time, I will update the demo code.

Comment: According to you log, it indicates that the table entity is existing. If you want to insert or update the existing table entity. We just need to change `$batchOperation.Insert(entity)` to  `$batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($entity)`. I also update the code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But how to add the delete operation in the same script.Please update when you are free in the above script.If I delete any entities in the csv files those changes need to be deleted in the azure tables.Please update your answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to keep the records in the azure storage table that are synchronizing with you csv file. If it is that case, could  remove the azure table and create a new one using the same name with csv file record. I have updated the code, please have a try.

Comment: ,I don't want to delete entire table and insert again.Because it is not a good practice as my table has thousands of entries everytime I can't delete and reinsert again.Even my development team not suggested to do.So please tell me any update method is available so that it will search for the existing entities and insert or delete new or old entities respectively.Kindly update me.

Comment: `Because it is not a good practice as my table has thousands of entries everytime I can't delete and reinsert again`. I recommond to delete the table and recreate  the table. As in your case you just need to keep the records that in your csv file. The way you mentioned that  want to check any updates, then need to loop  each record in the csv to compare with table records.  Based on my experience,it is not a good way to do that.

Comment: I have currently one issue as my csv file data is having different types of languages .Suppose < kï¿½rzlich > this string is the actual string in csv file but while deploying this data its converting to<  k�rzlich > in azure tables.So how to overcome from this issue ?

Comment: ,another issue is like I have 80000 rows in my table.csv file while deploying into azure it took more than 100 minutes .May I know what is the reason and why its taking that much of time? Any solution for this or any idea how to deploy within less time ?